# How do I execute a simple shell-command as a groovy script in the active choice parameter in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get the names of directories in a given directory. To try things out i used a regular pipeline, here's the working code:

```
foundDirectories = sh(script: "ls -1 'X:\\example\\directory'", returnStdout: true).split()
    foundDirectories.each { key ->
        println(key)
    }
```

I modified the code a bit to make it useful as a Parameter-Script:

```
foundDirectories = sh(script: "ls -1 'X:\\example\\directory'", returnStdout: true).split()

return foundDirectories
```

I tried to use this code in the `Active Choice Parameter` to be able to pick between the found directories when building with parameters. When i click on the "Build with parameters" button and the menu shows up, the script apparently doesn't work because the box stays empty. If I add a fallback script, it gets executed.

Do I have to add some code around it or do sh-commands just not work natively?

Comment: Yo cant use Jenkins keywords like sh in groovy scripts that are not part of a pipeline. You can use the groovy [File](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) class to achieve this or use the [Filesystem List Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin/)

Comment: You should implement this as a global var method within a shared library and then it will work after importing the lib.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I didn't know that i cant use Jenkins keywords in the groovy part, that fixed it. I now have a different approach, using the File class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below command it will list all the files in given directory. I tried it linux system.

even you can filter files based on regex by using `eachFileMatch(regex)`.

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
def list=[]
new File("X:\\example\\directory").eachFile() { 
  file -> list.add(file.getName())
}
return list
```